# NHibernate TooManyRowsAffectedException while trying to delete multiple objects

Tags: .net, oracle, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

Basically I'm getting this exception while trying to delete a collection of entities with nHibernate. Below is my code

```
   public void DeleteAll<T>(IList<T> entities)
   {
      using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
      { 
        try
        {
             entities.ForEach(e=>session.Delete(e));
             tx.Commit(); 
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
             tx.Rollback();
        }
      }
   }
```

Using hql works without any issue but I'd prefer to stick to the LINQish approach.. Oh and I'm connecting to an Oracle database.

Comment: this exception is thrown if a delete operation deletes more rows than expected. can you check the sql generated and the database table to see, which statement could potentially delete more than one row?

Comment: I understand why the exception was thrown, it only expects 1 row to be affected (in this case deleted), but why???? Nhprof doesn't work in our corporate network environment :(

Comment: log with log4net `NHIbernate.SQL` into a file. copy the sqls there in an oracle client and run them there to see which one deletes more than one row

Comment: I've plugged log4net to the project and to my surprise, nHibernate appears to be doing 2 selects before delete. What is strange is that the first select has a where clause with rownum <= 1. I suspect this is the reason why the exception was thrown. Any ideas ?

Comment: such selects are often a sign that the unsaved value mapping is not correct or that the entity has childs which have childs on their own

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete item by foreach, try for and be careful with index of for, after remove set index --